# jquery .then does not throw errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

using $.get promise (jquery 3.3.1) won't display any error, which makes debugging impossible

```
$.get('/').then(function() {
    console.log(undef)
})

fetch('/').then(function() {
    console.log(undef)
})
```

The first example is silent, no error thrown

The  second example throws as expected "Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: undef is not defined"

Is it a jquery bug or am I using it in a wrong way?
How'd you suggest using fetch instead? I'm concerned about browser comatibility

Comment: Hello orfaust! Did you try chaining a .catch(function() {}) after the .then() ? That is where the errors are caught (one option). Also - you're trying to console.log a value (undef) which I don't think is defined anywhere. Is there a place in your code where you set a value for the variable "undef"?

Comment: I am unable to replicate your problem. The error is thrown correctly in the JS example using `$.get()`: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/kzfmb6xc/1/. If you mean that the error is coming from the AJAX request itself, then see the answers below regarding the use of `fail()`

Comment: *using $.get promise (jquery 3.3.1) won't display any error* - it **does** throw an error using the code you've provided, where the `$.get` is successful and goes into the `.then`

Comment: @saglamcem yes, using .catch solved the problem. I put the "undef" on purpose to produce an error. Problem with jquery is that using chrome console, the error will appear only if you have warnings active, which normally I keep turned off

Comment: @orfaust wow, apparently it's been some time haha. good to hear it's solved. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can add the fail function in the chain:

```
$.get('/').then(function() {
    console.log(undef);
})
.fail(function(){
    console.log("Error");
})
```

[Reference](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Answer (score 3):

This is by design. `then()` only executes when a request completes successfully.

If you want to know when a request has failed add a [`fail()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/#deferred-fail-failCallbacks-failCallbacks) handler:

```
$.get('/').then(function() {
  console.log(undef);
}).fail(function() {
  // something went wrong...
});
```